# Stay on same page after button click event

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We use a survey link for feedback A suffix is use after the URL to make sure all SP components are not seen. When suffix is used there is a cancel button at the bottom which needs to be hidden or removed. And also when user clicks on finish button it navigates to a blank page, is it possible to give an alert like "Thanks for your feedback" and stay on the same page after button click event.

I am using this piece of code and this doesn't help.

```
<input type="button" Text="Finish" value="Form Action" name="btnFormAction0" onclick="javascript:     {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent ('__commit)')};alert('Your survey has been submitted  Successfully');window.parent.location='https://team.SharePoint.com/teams/Prod/Lists/Comm_Mgmt/newform.aspx?IsDlg=1'" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javascript code inside of the `onclick` attribute has errors.

```
GenFireServerEvent ('__commit)'
```

Should be

```
GenFireServerEvent('__commit')
```

If the page is still redirected, then I believe it may be due to some code in the `GenFireServerEvent` function or an HTTP 300 Redirection Response from your backend.

Comment: It's not a different URL, its the current page URL that I'm trying to retain after the button click event.

Comment: Ok, I removed that bit from my answer. Try and update your code as I suggested and see if the redirection still happens.

Comment: Ah congrats. It's always trickier to find javascript errors when the code is embedded in an HTML attribute. If you can, you should separate the onclick code into a <script> tag or javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that, your finish button redirect user to a new page, then on the new page, you create a on document ready call, over there you can trigger an alter function. please me know if you need more details about this.

cheers

Comment: No I am not trying to redirect to a new page, instead I 'm trying to stay on the same page by giving an alert.